# Why does tmux bind externally accessible ports?

Tags: tmux

I am performing a quick audit of services listening on external interfaces on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine, and tmux is binding TCP *:50994 and *:59147 as reported by `netstat -l`.

I can connect to this port from another computer on the network (barring any firewall settings), but I can't find any documentation about why it's binding an external port. What is the purpose of this and is there a way to stop it?

Comment: Does wireshark tell you anything about traffic going over those ports?

Comment: I shared this question on the tmux IRC channel and they are asking for you to post your tmux.conf

Comment: Where is your netstat output? `tmux` only uses UNIX sockets...

Comment: There is no tmux.conf passed in. Running `tmux show -g` outputs [this](http://pastebin.com/gmL2RBEU). It looks like byobu changed the status bar.

Comment: `netstat -l` shows only: "unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     23223    3682/tmux           /tmp/tmux-1000/default"

`sudo lsof | grep 'tmux' | grep 'LISTEN'` shows

tmux       3682          user_name   12u     IPv4              23074      0t0        TCP *:60047 (LISTEN)
tmux       3682          user_name   13u     IPv4              23077      0t0        UDP *:40754 
tmux       3682          user_name   14u     IPv4              23078      0t0            TCP *:56417 (LISTEN)

Comment: Can't reproduce at all, and I can't remotely think of a way an inet socket would show up in lsof but not netstat. Tried with byobu too. Also looked through tmux source and there doesn't seem to be any function that includes usage of TCP. You might want to check your tmux install source.. ?

Comment: Looking at the output of `netstat -l` how are you sure that it is tmux, as the output of that command doesn't even shown the associated process name.  You need the `-p` switch for that.

Comment: Notice that the port numbers are different in the output in your comment than in the question. So it looks like it's binding random ephemeral ports.

Comment: Don't you have some chroot / lxc containers installed, so the process id would match tmux on the host but would be actually a different process in the container ?

Comment: It needn't be tmux, it could well be something tmux links against. I seem to recall that many moons ago, some nss ldap module ended up with i.e. bash listening. (Although - this may have been udp). If you really wanted to get to the bottm, run tmux through gdb, break on listen (or socket, or somesuch), and look at the call-stack to see where it happens.

Answer (score 1):

It is tmux and it is a Unix socket. Tmux apparently uses server sockets to allow for independent tmux servers to be run. `man tmux`

Run tmux with no flags

```
tmux

$ ss -l |grep tmux
u_str  LISTEN     0      128    /tmp/tmux-1000/default 62749                 * 0
```

Then run tmux with `-S /tmp/tmux.sock` and see that the change in the socket path.

```
$ ss -l |grep tmux
u_str  LISTEN     0      128    /tmp/tmux.sock 62765                 * 0
```

Note, It is not TCP. This can be seen from using the flags `-t` (tcp) and `-l` (listening)

```
$ ss -tl
(returns no lines but the headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

are you using tcsh? https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=204429 has a similar-ish problem where starting tmux on tcsh results in dns queries.